# Hamiltonian in a semiconductor quantum well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, hamiltonian

I am currently studying for a photonics exam, and in particular the topic of this lecture is the energy dispersion of a quantum well in a semiconductor heterojunction. My professor wrote a particular hamiltonian in the z direction that I don't really understand.
In the x,y directions he assumed almost free electrons so $\Psi_{k_x k_y}(x,y)\sim e^{\vec K\cdot\vec{r})} $, having energy $E_{xy}=\frac{\hbar^2 K^2}{2m^*} $, with $\vec K=(k_x,k_y)$.
In the z direction, he wrote the following Hamiltonian problem:
$$
H_zF(z)=\left[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_j^*}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2} +V_j(z)+V_j^K \right]F(z)=E_zF(z)
$$
Where j=w or b, depending on whether we are considering the wave function inside or outside the well (so, the effective masses and the potentials inside or outside the barrier).
So, $V_j(z)=\cases{0 & $0<z<L_z$\\V_0 & otherwise}$ is the confinement potential. What I don't understand is $V_j^K=\frac{\hbar^2K^2}{2m^*_j}$, which my professor states accounts for the delocalization of the electrons over the x and y directions as a kind of "kinetic potential". What is this?

Since the electrons are confined over the direction of the well z, but not over the x and y directions, I understand that the ansatz for the solution would be something of the form of a Bloch wave in the x,y directions and a different function F in the z direction, which will be the eigenfunctions of a potential well (sin or cos in an infinite potential well): $\Psi(\vec{r})=u(x,y)e^{i*(k_x x+k_y y)}F(z) $. Assuming a very weak periodic potential justifies the switch from a Bloch wave to a free electron, sure. But a wave function like this would be separable in a separable Hamiltonian, which would give the total energy as the sum $E=E_{xy}+E_{z,n}$, which would be the correct result.

So, what is the point in expressing this "kinetic potential" inside the z-direction  Hamiltonian?